# COMO PODRIA CORREGIR ESTE CODIGO

Tags: php

ESTE ES MI INDEX.

```
        include_once 'bin/conexion/Conexion.php';        
    include_once 'bin/persistencia/Crud.php';
    $crud= new Crud("usu");//este es el nombre la la tabla

    $id=$crud->insert([
        "nom_usu"=> "richyto"]);
    echo "el ID insertado es ". $id;
    echo "<br>";
    //permite mostrar los registros de la DB
    $lista=$crud->get();
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($lista);
    echo "<pre>"
```

Y AQUI ESTA EL PROBLEMA, CUANDO DESEO INGRESAR EL REGISTRO DEL INDEX NO PROCEDE, PODRIAN AYUDARME POR FAVOR.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Que error recibis? donde esta el codigo que hace el insert? el codigo que pasaste no hace nada.

Answer (score 0):

prueba utilizando try y catch para saber cuál es el problema:

```
include_once 'bin/conexion/Conexion.php';        
include_once 'bin/persistencia/Crud.php';

try {
    $crud= new Crud("usu");//este es el nombre la la tabla
    $id=$crud->insert(["nom_usu"=> "richyto"]);
    echo "el ID insertado es ". $id;
    echo "<br>";
    //permite mostrar los registros de la DB
    $lista=$crud->get();
    echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($lista);
    echo "<pre>"
}
catch(Exception $ex) {
    echo "<div style='background-color:#FF0000;'>" . $ex->getMessage() . "</div>";
}
```